# Un dictionnaire standard du français (référence)

Tags: ressources, lexique, dictionnaires

Je travaille sur un petit projet (logiciel), ce qui sera une référence générale de la langue française. C'est un logiciel qui analyserait du texte français. Malheureusement je trouve que la plus grande partie du travail est de récrire un dictionnaire (standard) pour qu'il soit électronique (sur mon ordinateur, **dans un format lisible par le logiciel**).

Je n'ai pas envie de récrire entièrement un dictionnaire, donc j'en cherche un. Je peux utiliser un dictionnaire en ligne pour *chercher* des mots, mais ce n'est pas forcement ce dont j'ai besoin.

Ce que je *ne veux pas* faire, c'est acheter un dictionnaire (comme Le Robert), et récrire tous les mots (pas de définitions en ce moment) pour que je puisse les utiliser dans l'analyse du texte (il faut que le dictionnaire soit en format électronique). Mais quand même, je ne suis pas sûr de pouvoir utiliser tous les mots du Robert légalement (sans violer le droit d'auteur)...

Donc, la question: existe-t-il un dictionnaire qui (si possible) soit déjà électronique que je peux utiliser sans violer le droit d'auteur? Ou bien, existe-t-il une liste des mots de la langue française standard que je puisse utiliser?

Mes exigences/préférences sont les suivants:

1. Qu'il s'agit de la langue française *standard*.
2. Qu'il soit gratuit [dictionnaire ou même une liste des mots], ou pas trop chèr (moins de 75€).
3. Qu'il ait des **mots** que je peux utiliser (dans un format électronique), et ne soit pas un *logiciel complet* comme [Le Robert](http://www.lerobert.com/espace-numerique/telechargement/le-grand-robert-pc.html) ou [Le Littré](https://code.google.com/p/dictionnaire-le-littre/) ou un dictionnaire en ligne comme le [TLF](http://atilf.atilf.fr/).

L'objectif du projet est d'analyser du texte en français. Pour faire ça, je dois effectivement créer une liste des mots en français (des noms, des adjectifs, des verbes à l'infinitif, des pronoms, etc.) pour que je puisse les utiliser pour faire en sorte que le logiciel « lise » les paragraphes du texte, et de le faire analyser mot par mot. C'est pour ça que j'ai besoin d'un dictionnaire électronique et que je ne peux utiliser ni un dictionnaire « en ligne » ni un dictionnaire « complet » (comme Le Littré).

Pouvez-vous me conseiller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Si « analyser » veut dire « étudier automatiquement d'un point de vue syntaxique, morphologique ou sémantique »

Il existe en fait déjà des dictionnaires et des lexiques conçus pour le TAL. Ma référence de base est le [Lexique des Formes Fléchies du Français](http://alpage.inria.fr/~sagot/lefff.html) qui devrait largement suffire pour un petit projet.

Pour aller plus loin, le [Lexique-Grammaire](http://ladl.univ-mlv.fr/DonneesLinguistiques/Lexiques-Grammaires/Presentation.html) est à ma connaissance le lexique de français le plus complet existant, mais il est possible qu'il n'ait pas encore été totalement numérisé et distribué, ça fait quelques années que je ne l'ai pas touché.

Soit dit en passant, vérifie que tu ne réinventes pas la roue et que le logiciel que tu veux réaliser ou un équivalent n'existe pas déjà. Pour un état de l'art en TAL syntaxe et morphologie, [la page de Benoît Sagot](http://alpage.inria.fr/~sagot/links.html) est un bon point de départ. Si tu as des questions précises, ping moi [chez Cosette](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1098/chez-cosette) où dans [lɪŋˈgwɪstɪks](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1336/lgwstks) (puisque le TAL fait partie de leur portefolio).

Comment: Ça va me prendre un peu de temps pour écrire un algorithme de lire le fichier - mais bon, c'est plus ou moins ce que je cherchais. Il y a des petits nuances, mais ça va aller! A votre remarque alors: vérifie que tu ne réinventes pas la roue...* Moi je sais bien que ce type de logiciel existe déjà; franchement, je vais faire ce projet pour améliorer ma connaissance de la langage et linguistique française, et aussi comme projet pour mes études à l'université. Merci pour le ressource, je ne savais pas comment rechercher! Très bien apprécié :)

Answer (score 2):

Pourquoi ne pas s'appuyer sur  *[dicollecte](http://www.dicollecte.org/home.php?prj=fr)* utilisé par *[Apache OpenOffice](http://www.openoffice.org/fr/)* ou *[LibreOffice](http://fr.libreoffice.org/)*.

Il a le mérite d'être libre, mis à jour régulièrement et pérenne.

De plus il y a des passerelles, des routines, des paquets tous faits pour analyser et présenter les mots dans les traitements de texte cités.